# How to do new line in messages_en.properties file in keycloak

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, keycloak, properties-file

I am modifying keycloak messages_en.properties file for the error message in regexpattern mismatch:

```
invalidPasswordRegexPatternMessage=Password must contain at least one special character\n
Password must contain at least one upper case character\n
Password must contain at least one numerical character\n
Password should not contain blank space\n
Password should consist of 8-15 characters
```

But it wont display a newline using \n in the toast that pop-up in the UI.
[image: here is the image]

I tried backslash only but it also wont work.

Comment: use br tag instead.

Comment: didn't work it shows <br> in the UI also @BarathVutukuri

Comment: you need to modify the UI code. You shouldn't display the message as it is. Set the message as innerhtml to the element in the UI.

Comment: i found the ui-code it is inside here:
<strong>{{notification.header}}</strong> {{notification.message}}
.Now if i inspect element it the <br> became &lt;br&gt; what is this mean.

Password must contain at least one special character&lt;br&gt;Password must contain at least one upper case character&lt;br&gt; @BarathVutukuri

Comment: &lt means less than symbol &gt means greater than symbol.

Comment: i think the js file converts it into a text not an html. I'm having a hard time to locate where this notification.message is located in js.

Comment: if you can help me to find here is the github link: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/admin @BarathVutukuri . The html is index.ftl

Comment: try declaring the properties file like prop2=first line of prop2 \n \
second line of prop2 \n \
third line of prop2 @LogronJ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168198/discussion-between-barathvutukuri-and-logronj).

Comment: unfortunately i can't accessed your link it's blocked :'(

Comment: i already resolved it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use `<br>` in the message, but you must append **?no_esc** to the message output in the freemarker .ftl file.

Examples:

- `${msg("msgId")?no_esc}`
- `${kcSanitize(message.summary)?no_esc}`

Answer (score 0):

I used br tag and then in html i added: ng-bind-html="notification.message"
And in the services.js file i found the notifications.error there so i added 'ngSanitize' as a dependency based on this guide: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-bind-html.asp